# Copying and Merging Last Columns from Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 30 worksheets with 20+ columns each and a large number of rows. How might one go about telling Excel to select the last column that contains text in the second row from each worksheet and place them in a new worksheet?  The following code seems close:

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Dim bottomD As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets(Array("A", "B", "C", "D"))
        ws.Activate
        bottomD = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A2:D" & bottomD).Copy Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Instead of `bottomD = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` I should be able to use something like `furthest = Range(Columns.Count & "2").End(xlRight).Column`.  I have a couple of questions:

1) Does my first change make sense?

2) Is there a way to have the macro look through a loop instead of `Sheets(Array("A", "B", "C", "D"))`?  In my case the sheets all have similar names so it would be possible to simply enumerate `Array("Name" & i)` for worksheet number i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to access worksheets in a loop using an index into the Worksheets collection.  See code below.

Use data type `Long` not `Integer` unless you are using a 16-bit computer.  `Integer` specifies a 16-bit number which on a 32-bit computer requires special processing.  Also with Excel 2007 and later, an `Integer` is not big enough to hold larger row numbers.

Avoid activating worksheets because it is a slow command.  If it is essential to activate Worksheets, include

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

which will reduce screen flash as the screen is repainted each time you switch worksheets,

`furthest = Range(Columns.Count & "2").End(xlRight).Column` is the correct idea but the implementation is faulty.  `Columns.Count` returns the number of columns for your version of Excel.  For Excel 2003, there are 256 columns.  Later versions have 16384 columns.  So you are specifying `Range(2562)` or `Range(163842)`.  See code below for correct syntax.

I do not understand `Range("A2:D" & bottomD).Copy Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`  You say you want to copy a column but `Range("A2:D" & bottomD)` is not a column.  You are then placing all the source columns in column A of worksheet “Summary”.  Is this really what you wanted?  In the code below, I have placed the source columns across the sheet headed by the worksheet name which I would have thought was a more useful arrangement.  If this is not what you want, I can adjust the code to give the result you do want.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergeColumns()

  Dim ColSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim ColSumCrnt As Long
  Dim InxWsht As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long
  Dim WshtSum As Worksheet

  Set WshtSum = Worksheets("Summary")

  ' Clear existing contents
  WshtSum.Cells.EntireRow.Delete
  ColSumCrnt = 1

  For InxWsht = 1 To Worksheets.Count

    With Worksheets(InxWsht)
      If .Name <> "Summary" Then

        ' Write worksheet name to row 1 of current column of "Summary"
        WshtSum.Cells(1, ColSumCrnt).Value = .Name

        ' This worksheet is not the summary so find the last
        ' column with a value in row 2.
        ColSrcCrnt = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        If .Cells(Rows.Count, ColSrcCrnt).Value <> "" Then
          ' Bottom cell of column used.  It will be lost.  Colour
          ' worksheet name to report error.
          WshtSum.Cells(1, ColSumCrnt).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
          RowSrcLast = Rows.Count - 1
        Else
          ' There is room for entire column in Summary
          RowSrcLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColSrcCrnt).End(xlUp).Row
        End If

        ' Copy column
        .Range(.Cells(1, ColSrcCrnt), _
               .Cells(RowSrcLast, ColSrcCrnt)).Copy Destination:=WshtSum.Cells(2, ColSumCrnt)

        ColSumCrnt = ColSumCrnt + 1     ' Step ready for next worksheet

      End If

    End With

  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked better and faster than anything I would have thought of.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm please it helped.